# Trying to pull/run docker images from docker hub on Minikube fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am very new to Kuberetes and I have done some work with docker previously. I am trying to accomplish following:

1. Spin up Minikube
2. Use Kube-ctl to spin up a docker image from docker hub.

I started minikube and things look like they are up and running. Then I pass following command

kubectl run nginx --image=nginx (Please note I do not have this image anywhere on my machine and I am expecting k8 to fetch it for me)

Now, when I do that, it spins up the pod but the status is `ImagePullBackOff`. So I ran `kubectl describe pod` command on it and the results look like following:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age              From               Message
  ----     ------     ----             ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  8m               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/ngix-67c6755c86-qm5mv to minikube
  Warning  Failed     8m               kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.2:52133->192.168.64.1:53: read: connection refused
  Normal   Pulling    8m (x2 over 8m)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     8m (x2 over 8m)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     8m               kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.2:40073->192.168.64.1:53: read: connection refused
  Normal   BackOff    8m (x3 over 8m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     8m (x3 over 8m)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Then I searched around to see if anyone has faced similar issues and it turned out that some people have and they did resolve it by restarting minikube using some more flags which look like below:

`minikube start --vm-driver="xhyve" --insecure-registry="$REG_IP":80`

when I do `nslookup` inside Minikube, it does resolve with following information:

```
Server:         10.12.192.22
Address:        10.12.192.22#53

Non-authoritative answer:
hub.docker.com  canonical name = elb-default.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io.
elb-default.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io       canonical name = us-east-1-elbdefau-1nlhaqqbnj2z8-140214243.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   us-east-1-elbdefau-1nlhaqqbnj2z8-140214243.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 52.205.36.130
Name:   us-east-1-elbdefau-1nlhaqqbnj2z8-140214243.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 3.217.62.246
Name:   us-east-1-elbdefau-1nlhaqqbnj2z8-140214243.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 35.169.212.184
```

still no luck. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try pulling the image manually using `docker pull nginx`? I think the problem is that you can't pull images from the docker hub in your environment. Change another registry from which you can pull images.

Comment: There error message suggests that the Docker daemon running in the minikube VM can't resolve the `registry-1.docker.io` hostname because the DNS nameserver it's configured to use for DNS resolution (`192.168.64.1:53`) is refusing connection. If you do `minikube ssh` and then run `nslookup hub.docker.com` what do you get?

Comment: I updated my qustion with nslookup information

Comment: It's strange to me that the Docker deamon is trying to resolve `registry-1.docker.io` via a nameserver at `192.168.64.1` but when you `nslookup` on the VM it's using a nameserver at `10.12.192.22`. I did an Internet search for "minkube Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53" and found an issue where someone made [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1906#issuecomment-361833738), seems identical to your problem, and seems specific to `xhyve`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta your hunch is correct. This was a 100% XHyve issue. re-installed minikube and configured it to use Virtual box and everything looks good. You can convert your comment into an answer if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There error message suggests that the Docker daemon running in the minikube VM can't resolve the `registry-1.docker.io` hostname because the DNS nameserver it's configured to use for DNS resolution (`192.168.64.1:53`) is refusing connection. It's strange to me that the Docker deamon is trying to resolve `registry-1.docker.io` via a nameserver at `192.168.64.1` but when you `nslookup` on the VM it's using a nameserver at `10.12.192.22`. I did an Internet search for "minkube Get registry-1.docker.io/v2: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53" and found an issue where someone made [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1906#issuecomment-361833738), seems identical to your problem, and seems specific to `xhyve`.

In that comment the person says:

> This issue does look like an xhyve issue not seen with virtualbox.

and

> Switching to **virtualbox** fixed this issue for me.
>
> I stopped minikube, deleted it, started it without `--vm-driver=xhyve` (minikube uses virtualbox driver by default), and then `docker build -t hello-node:v1 .` worked fine without errors

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was caused by running `dnsmasq`, a dns server, on my Mac using Homebrew, which caused the DNS requests to fail inside minikube. After stopping `dnsmasq`, everything worked.

Comment: You saved my day ! I'm using docker as driver on fedora 33.

Maybe the firewall should also be disabled

Comment: Also needed to reboot mac as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem with my local `minikube` setup and I wasn't able to pull any images I added to a simple deployment manifest.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
test1             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          68s
```

Tried to execute the below test:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test1
  labels:
    site: blog
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: nginx:latest
```

It was possible or fixed only after restarting the `minikube`.
Maybe the `dnsmasq` was really the cause in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

1. minukube running with default settings.
2. docker building your images
3. (*) configured minikube to point to your docker images local repo

And now minikube can't pull images from public "container" registries, like docker hub.

stop and start minikube, then point it back to your local docker images repo. The commands to do this (and (*) this):

```
minikube stop
minikube start
minikube -p minikube docker-env
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

Since running the above I was able to pull nginx, alpine and frens from hub.docker.come just by setting `image: alpine` in the yaml spec.

The issue was just a short drop in my network connectivity. So if you have no dns/vpn/xhyve complications and it just stops, the fix is easy enough.